# Mysql: count order totals from db1.order_tbl, db2.order_tbl, ..., dbN.order_tbl?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a sql query to count order totals:

> count order totals from db1.order_tbl, db2.order_tbl, ..., dbN.order_tbl

Comment: Why do you have separate tables?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine the tables in a `from` clause unless you are very careful.  Instead, aggregate them separately.  Here is one easy way:

```
select ( (select count(*) from db1.order_tbl) +
         (select count(*) from db2.order_tbl) +
         . . .
         (select count(*) from dbN.order_tbl)
       )
```

This assumes that "count order totals" means "count the rows".  If you have another aggregation in mind (such as `sum(order_total)`) then you can use that instead.